# PHP how to set variable1 if variable 2 equals certain value

Tags: php, arrays, variables, if-statement

Hi I'm trying to get one variable to set itself after an if statement on another variable, but I can't get the syntax right. Please help, this is the code that I've got so far.

```
$subtype = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subtype']);

if      $subtype == ['12m'] {$subprice = 273.78}
elseif  $subtype == ['6m']  {$subprice = 152.10}
elseif  $subtype == ('1m')  {$subprice = 30.42}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

```
if ($subtype == '12m')
  $subprice = 273.78;
elseif ($subtype == '6m')
  $subprice = 152.10;
elseif ($subtype == '1m')
  $subprice = 30.42;
```

Or with the [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement:

```
switch ($subtype) {
  case '12m': $subprice = 273.78; break;
  case '6m' : $subprice = 152.10; break;
  case '1m' : $subprice = 30.42; break;
}
```

Comment: @brew84 You're welcome. Please consider marking this as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark outline to its left.

Answer (score 2):

```
$subtype = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subtype']);

if      ($subtype == "12m") {$subprice = 273.78; }
elseif  ($subtype == "6m")  {$subprice = 152.10; }
elseif  ($subtype == "1m")  {$subprice = 30.42; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP [switch()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) to achieve that:

```
$subtype = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subtype']);

switch($subtype) {
  case "12m":
    $subprice = 273.78;
    break;
  case "6m":
    $subprice = 152.10;
    break;
  case "1m":
    $subprice = 30.42;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$subtype = htmlspecialchars($_POST['subtype']);

if      ($subtype == "12m") {$subprice = 273.78}
elseif  ($subtype == "6m")  {$subprice = 152.10}
elseif  ($subtype == "1m")  {$subprice = 30.42}
```